# localhost request cancelled in Microsoft Edge but not in Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, http, microsoft-edge, nodemon

i'm currently learning about nodejs and was working on a simple check on the url to see which html page to display.

But i ran into a problem when simply trying to type **localhost:"port"** into Microsoft Edge. Normally it would open up my index.html file, but now it shows up as "*Cancelled*" when i open up the dev tools in Edge. When i try some of the other sites like **localhost:"port"/login.html**, it works fine. It is only on the default **localhost:"port"**

I then thought i had written something wrong in my code, even though it worked earlier, so i tried typing in localhost:"port" into chrome instead, and it worked as expected.

Does anyone know if Edge can decide to "block" certain urls? I recall working with a http redirect which put me in an endless loop, and when i restarted the browser, this problem occured.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Which version of Edge and OS are you using? What is the detailed error showing when it doesn't work in Edge? Does the issue only occur in the NodeJS website or occur in all the other localhost: port website in your side?